# creating knowledge base from package

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor

I was dealing with one drl earlier , now I want multiple in the same package.Can anyone please guide me step by step how to do this?

What I have tried yet:

I have specified package in changeset file using webdav

```
<add>
<resource source="address/guvnor/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/webdav/packages/Name" type="DRL"/>
</add>
```

In my code m using

```
 ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("changeset.xml").
```

Where am I doing it wrong? Do I have to build or deploy package or somethng else in guvnor?

Answer (score 0):

I have done it in another way now instead of specifying package I specified all the files name in changeset:

add>

resource source="address/guvnor/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/webdav/packages/Name/File1.drl" type="DRL"/>

resource source="address/guvnor/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/webdav/packages/Name/File2.drl" type="DRL"/>

/add>

The main issue was when knowledge base was forming from different drl files , rules name were same in them.